# Issues when trying to throw custom exception from a custom error handler when validating XML with StAX

Tags: java, xml, exception, xsd, stax

I'm trying to implement a custom exception when validating `XML` against `XSD`, in order to return the line number and element in the error.

However, when I throw my custom exception in my error handler a `SAXException` is thrown with my exception contained in the message rather than my custom error.

When my `CustomXMLValidationException` is thrown in `CustomErrorHandler` -  I would like it to be caught in `validateXml()`:

```
public static String validateXml(InputStream inputXml) throws XMLStreamException {
        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = factory.newSchema(getXSD()).newValidator();
            XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(inputXml);
            validator.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler(reader));
            validator.validate(new StAXSource(reader));
        } catch (CustomXmlValidationException e) {
            return prepareValidationErrorMessageWithLineNo(e.getLineNo(), e.getMessage(), e.getElement());
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException | SAXException e) {
            return String.format("Validation error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is `CustomErrorHandler`:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private boolean isValid = true;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.isValid;
    }

    private XMLStreamReader reader;

    public CustomErrorHandler(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exc) throws SAXException {
        throw new CustomXmlValidationException(exc.getMessage(), exc.getLineNumber(), reader.getLocalName());
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exc) {

    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {

    }
```

And `CustomXmlValidationException`:

```
public class CustomXmlValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    int lineNo;
    String element;

    public CustomXmlValidationException(String message, int lineNo, String element) {
        super(message);
        this.lineNo = lineNo;
        this.element = element;
    }

    public int getLineNo() {
        return this.lineNo;
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}
```